# I've been trying to apply the polyRoots function with "TI-nspire cx" but it keeps returning an empty value, what is happening?

Tags: ti-nspire

I've been able to use the polyRoots function since day one, but all of a sudden it stopped working and it keeps returning an empty result,does someone know what is happening? Thank you in advance! [This is the return I get, I´ve put a very simple one so that I know it's not an input problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJrxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The function `polyRoots` only returns the real-valued zeros of a polynomial. Instead, you can use `cPolyRoots` to include complex-valued zeros, which will -- in your case -- look something like this:

```
cPolyRoots(3*x^2+4*x+5,x)
                            {-2/3-sqrt(11)/3*i,-2/3+sqrt(11)/3*i}
```

In case you're not familiar with complex numbers, here's a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) regarding them. Basically, `i=sqrt(-1)`, which is a number that isn't present anywhere on the real number line; the real number line only includes negative infinity through positive infinity.